# BSOD with Windows 7, error code f4, SSD implied?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, ssd, bsod

I'm currently facing blue screens on Windows 7 64-bits, that happen 45 minutes or so after system start-up.

The error code I get is 0xF4, which, according to MS bug check codes corresponds to the [CRITICAL_OBJECT_TERMINATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff560372.aspx) error.

I've tried to analyze the minidump that Windows created, but can't really get what's causing the error. It's said to happen in `ntoskrnl.exe` which seems to be Windows Kernel process, most of the time at the address `7efc0`.

The only clue I have is that it might be associated with my system HDD, which is an Crucial M4 with 64 GB, because when my computer automatically reboot, it gets stuck on

> Auto-detecting AHCI device 0

and nothing happens until I reboot manually by completely shutting down my computer.

So my question is, **what causes the problem in my case, is it my SSD ?**

I have the feeling that it might be this, but then I don't know how to be sure, and then if this is possible to repair that, or if buying a new disk is the only option.

If this helps, I paste the Minidump infos that I got with BlueScreenView :

```
=================================================
Dump File         : 080413-27081-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 04/08/2013 22:27:34
Bug Check String  : CRITICAL_OBJECT_TERMINATION
Bug Check Code    : 0x000000f4
Parameter 1       : 00000000`00000003
Parameter 2       : fffffa80`0543bb30
Parameter 3       : fffffa80`0543be10
Parameter 4       : fffff800`031d7460
Caused By Driver  : ntoskrnl.exe
Caused By Address : ntoskrnl.exe+7efc0
File Description  : NT Kernel & System
Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
File Version      : 6.1.7601.17944 (win7sp1_gdr.120830-0333)
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+7efc0
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\Windows\Minidump\080413-27081-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 8
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7601
Dump File Size    : 292 224
Dump File Time    : 04/08/2013 22:29:56
==================================================
```

Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried setting the drive to IDE mode in the BIOS?

Comment: @trpt4him Yep I tried that, but it didn't change anything... I still got a crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had similar problem with 128gb version.
Upgrading firmware helped 
http://www.crucial.com/support/firmware.aspx

Comment: I'll give a try ! Thanks for the suggestion !

Comment: Welp, it didn't change anything, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: upload the .dmp file. The M4 has indeed a 5000 hrs bug which can cause bugchecks. So updating the firmware was a good idea. http://forums.crucial.com/t5/Solid-State-Drives-SSD/BSOD-Crucial-M4/td-p/79098

Comment: @magicandre1981 Just found out about it, I performed the firmware update thatnks to another version that seems to be newer, and that did the trick. No more crashes. Hell of an hilarious bug from what I read ! Thanks !

Comment: ok, great to hear that the firmware update fixed it :)